# No https links on https page

Tags: bug

When I am using  "https://security.stackexchange.com" there appears to be no "https" link on two buttons: "Chat" and "Blog".

So if I am logged-in and I go to "Chat" it says I need to logon. However the "Log-In" button doesn't work I think because I am already logged-on the "https". By clicking it it just redirects me back to the page I was on.

See screenshot below:

[image: Cut Screenshot]

Comment: I think you should precise what browser you are using, and if you are using any SSL-related browser plugin (like HTTPS Everywhere which caused some [similar issues](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1986/32746) by the past). I've quickly tested it but do not seem to encounter any issue currently (cookies emitted by the `stackexchange.com` domain are allowed for unsecured connections here, you may want to check this on your side too).

Comment: My specific setting is that I don't keep cookies between browser restarts. So every day I perform logon. I use only security.stackexchange.com at the moment and sometimes I visit Unix.SE. I can reproduce this in 64bit Linux - Firefox and Chrome in latest versions when logged-in and logged-out.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on latest linux chrome fresh install - after deleting config and cache settings and without being logged.

Comment: I've just tested this again from another computer, but can sadly still not reproduce your issue: the links are indeed HTTP, but I do not have any log-in issue since `.stackexchange.com` cookies are allowed for any kind of connection (both secure and unsecure). Have you checked is these cookies were defined the same way on your system? What you describe is the usual symptom for session cookies being restricted to secured connection only.

Comment: OK the problem manifests in the simplest way that when I am on SSL enabled site, when I am using site normally e..g clicking responses and positing replies on the same site, I am directed and redirected to the site without SSL. And this is serious bug which needs to be fixed. SSL Everywhere is the solution for the moment. There are more issues associated with this problem, so it's both the links for viewing replies but also during positing. After post is submitted I am back on the site without SSL. I am not sure now if the post goes over SSL, I'll check it out now.

Comment: When I logon over HTTPS, the cookies are not allowed for HTTP. The point is it used to work fine week ago.

Answer (score 1):

I see it, too, using Chromium 52.0.2743.116-1~deb8u1 on Debian stable (Jessie). I do have HTTPS Everywhere, Privacy Badger and a couple other extensions installed. Here's a screenshot of View Source on https://security.stackexchange.com and searching for 'blog' so you can see the actual URLs presented to me:

[image]